# OnPropertyChanged does not update the CollectionView (.NET MAUI)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui

I have the following controls on a page.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
<Button Text="Add an item" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
<Label Text="{Binding Items.Count}" />
<Label Text="{Binding Items.Capacity}" />
```

And I have the following code in a view model

```
public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new();

[RelayCommand]
void AddItem()
{
    Items.Add("item");
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
}
```

After clicking on the Button labels update but the CollectionView does not. Why?

Comment: Adding an element to the collection that is held by the Items property does not actually change that property. The change notification is ignored because the value of the Items property has not changed. Use ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: @Clemens But for example if I add the `<Label Text="{Binding Items.Count}" />`, then this Label updates after clicking.

Comment: I dont understand who closed the question!

Comment: In order to update the UI automatically, your collection must be an ObservableCollection annotated as an [ObservableProperty] like this:
[ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<string> items = new();
Check this sample: https://github.com/imoulas/sample-maui-net-expense-app

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas It was closed as a duplicate. The answer is in the duplicate.

Comment: `{Binding Items.Count}` is different, because the `Count` property has actually changed its value.